# Extracting frequency from list

Tags: python, sorting

I used Counter to sort a list, and I am trying to extract the frequency from the sorted list. What can I do to get those numbers eg. 2022 and 1393 for some calculations?

```
from collections import Counter
title_file = open("title.txt", "r")

headers = title_file.readline()
titles = []

for line in title_file.readlines():
  line.rstrip()
  (name, title) = line.split('\t')
  titles.append(title)

titlecount = Counter(titles).most_common()
print "%s" % (titlecount)
#sample output: [('PROFESSOR', 2022), ('REGISTERED NURSE - LEVEL B', 1393)]
```

Comment: `titlecount[0][1], titlecount[1][1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list you get from counter is a list of tuples. The first element is the name of the token, the second is a count of its occurrence.

Simply loop through the list:

```
title_count = Counter(titles).most_common()
for name,count in title_count:
    print('{} was found {} times'.format(name, count))
```